# Python findAll not working on beautifulsoup 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a html file and write the results to a csv file. 
The html file is:

```
<table BORDER='1' CELLSPACING='0' CELLPADDING='0'>
<tr>
    <td><small>15</small></td >
    <td><small><small>Cat</small></small></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><small><small>16</small></small></td>       
    <td><small><small>&nbsp;</small></small></td>       
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><small>17</small></td >
    <td><small><small>Dog</small></small></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the code I have atm is:

```
import csv
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs (open("Animals.html"))
for i in soup.findAll('small'):
if "&nbsp;" in i.text:
    i.string = '-'

print soup

f = csv.writer(open("Animals.csv", "a"))   # Open the output file for writing before the loop

trs = soup.findAll('tr')

for tr in trs:

    tds = tr.findAll("td")

    try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
    id = str(tds[0].get_text()) # This structure isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
    animal = str(tds[1].get_text())

except:
    print "Bad tr string"
    continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error

f.writerow([id, animal])
```

When I print out the contents of soup after replacing the `%nbsp;` I get:

```
<table BORDER='1' CELLSPACING='0' CELLPADDING='0'>
<tr>
    <td><small>15</small></td >
    <td><small></small><small>Cat</small></td > 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><small><small>16</small></small></td >      
    <td><small></small><small>-</small></td >       
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><small>17</small></td >
    <td><small></small><small>Dog</small></td >
</tr>
</table>
```

But when I look at the .csv file it is empty. However if I change the code to use BeautifulSoup 4, then I can't replace the `&nbsp;` but the results will be saved to the .csv file. The other code that I use is:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs (open("Animals.html"))

f = csv.writer(open("Animals.csv", "w"))   # Open the output file for writing before the loop

trs = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:

tds = tr.find_all("td")

try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
    id = str(tds[0].get_text()) # This structure isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
    animal = str(tds[1].get_text())

except:
    print "Bad tr string"
    continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error

f.writerow([id, animal])
```

The reason why that one won't do me is because I want the `&nbsp;` to be replaced with `-` and I haven't been able to get that (the find_all()) to work with beautifulsoup 4.
What is causing the information to be saved to the csv file and how can I fix it (and/or get it working with beautifulsoup 4)?

Comment: Sorry for being able to propose an alternative solution only, but: if the document's content is simple enough, why don't you try to replace `&nbsp;` in `<small>` elements with `-` by using a regular expression, before processing the content with Beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup 4 will convert that 'nbsp;' into a Unicode character \xa0 when the 'soup' is constructed. If you search-and-replace on that unicode character it will work:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for i in soup.find_all('small'):
    i.string.replace_with(i.string.replace(u'\xa0', '-'))
```

The syntax there is a little verbose. This is because `i.string` is not a string, but a `bs4.element.NavigableString`. You can't edit these in place with a straightforward `i.string.replace(...)`; instead you must call beautifulsoup's own `replace_with` method.

`replace_with` accepts just one argument, so we have to generate the new version of the string and pass it in. For this we can use Python's built in `replace` method for strings, to strip out the u'\xa0' characters and replace them with '-'

Alternatively, you could just use regular expressions on the original HTML. If all you need is to replace all `&nbsp;` instances with a `-`:

```
import re

newhtml = re.sub(r'&nbsp;', '-', html)
```

Though you could customise this further so it only affects `<small>` tags - let me know if you'd like this added to the answer.